# How to display a complex table with Angular Material

Tags: angular, material-table

i try to create a table with
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples
and I hope somebody can help me.

The first column shall show times, on the left side I want to have time ["09:00" .. "18:00"]. I take the data from an enum.

Then I want so show for every room the room's content i.e tracks in the room. I take the data from   roomsWithTracks: RoomWithTracks. Look like this https://md-devdays.de/act-plan/act-plan.

My problem is that I have two datascources (times and RoomWithTracks) and I have a second array inside RoomWithTracks.

-How to display the time for every row?
-How to go through the array "room.timeSlots" and show only tracks that are filled, i.e that
matched to the time?

Here's my code:

```
export enum Time {
  nine      = "09:00",
  ten       = "10:00",
  eleven    = "11:00",
  twelve    = "12:00",
  thirteen  = "13:00",
  fourteen  = "14:00",
  fifteen   = "15:00",
  sixteen   = "16:00",
  seventeen = "17:00",
  eighteen  = "18:00"  
}

export interface RoomWithTracks {
  id: number;
  roomTitle: string;    
  timeSlots: TimeSlot[]    
}
```

TimeSlots are filled with the enum Time. timeSlots includes all times from Time.
If there is a track a the given time, the track is filled in TimeSlot corredponding to the time otherwise the track is not filled.

```
export interface TimeSlot {
  time: Time;
  track?: Track;
}
```

Data in ts-file

```
  ...
  roomsWithTracks: RoomWithTracks[]=[]
  time = Object.values(Time)
  displayColumns : string[];

  setDisplayColumn() {
    this.displayColumns.push("Time")

    this.roomsWithTracks.forEach(room =>
      this.displayColumns.push(room.roomTitle)
    )
  }
  ...
```

That's my table in html file. I do not know how to put the data inside...

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z3">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="roomsWithTracks">

      <!-- Time Colum-->
      **TODO: How to display the time for every row?**
      <ng-container matColumnDef="todo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Time </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let time"> </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Room Colum-->
      **TODO: How to go through the array "room.timeSlots" and show only tracks that are filled, i.e that
      matched to the time?**
      <ng-container matColumnDef="roomTitle">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="let room"> {{room.roomTitle}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let room"> {{room.timeSlots...}} </td>
      </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns;"></tr>
  </table>


</div>
```

I hope somebody can help me!
Thank you! ;)

Comment: share a basic stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Answer (score 0):

Use a mat-table to show a "calendar" perhafs it's not a good idea. But you can do it. The only is that the datasource becomes an array with so many elements as times you have. As "properties" of the elements of the arrays are the rooms. push you need a property "rowspan" for this rooms fill more that one period of time

This array of elements you need create with the data you received

Be carefull, A column that has a rowspan, the next elements should be as rowspan -1. So you can write some like

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef ">
  {{ column }}
</th>
<ng-container  *matCellDef="let element">
  <td mat-cell *ngIf="column!='position' || element.rowspan!=-1" 
    
    [attr.rowspan]="element.rowspan?element.rowspan:null"
  >
    {{ element[column] }}
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-hide-columns-pure-obserabl-vm4sdm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) you has an example of a table with rowspan

But I'm not pretty sure that this can help you :(